# autosys Extract specific jobs from jil file

Tags: autosys, jil

I have thousands of jobs in Autosys JIL file, I would like to extract specific jobs starting with admin-* from jil files.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract them from the autosys itself as a jil file. On the cmd line just do:

```
autorep -qJ admin-* > admin_jobs.jil
```

That will create a file admin_jobs.jil with the search criteria.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

In the Autosys portal under **Enterprise Command Line** tab

Select your **Servers**.
Under **Command** enter below and click **Execute**.

`autorep -J admin-% -q`

This will provide all jobs starting with "admin-".